# converting files in to single zip using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, zipcode

I am using C# code for aspx pages. I need to convert multiple files in to single zip file that can be readable by windows default zip software.

Can any one have an idea about it...?

Comment: if you have written your own code, may be you can post it so then it will be easy how you are doing it for a single file.

Comment: can you tell how are you sending multiple files, you are doing it by URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an free library like

http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 7):

See this tutorial: [Creating Zip archives in .NET (without an external library like SharpZipLib)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx)

```
ZipFile zip= new ZipFile("MyNewZip.zip"); 
zip.AddDirectory("My Pictures", true); // AddDirectory recurses subdirectories
zip.Save();
```

Or you can use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx).

Comment: How can i get the System.io.packaging. It is not coming in .aspx.cs page?

Comment: By default, in aspx.cs file System.IO is working. but System.IO.Packaging  is not working.

Comment: Ya. I got the solution that just adding WindowsBase.dll Ok its working fine.  Thank you.

Comment: If i want to distribute my code, DotNetZip or SharpZipLib which one is free or low cost for developer point of view.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is a good open source one, without any licensing issue.

Comment: is that DotNetZip free for licensing.

Comment: @Ramesh.kvbr - I believe so, it's MS-Pl, but read the doc, I'm not a lawyer :-)

Answer (score 1):

//use this library SharpZipLib.
 using this you can send multiple file for zipping which user selected and can save it to the physical path you specify either on client.

```
public string zipfile(string[] files)
    {


        string[] filenames = new string[files.Length];


            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0, 10// set it according to your filename).ToString();
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "");
        string DirectoryName = filenames[0].Remove(filenames[0].LastIndexOf('/'));
        DirectoryName = DirectoryName.Substring(DirectoryName.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace("\\", "");

        try
        {

            string newFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "the physical path where you want to save it" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
            if (File.Exists(newFile))
                File.Delete(newFile);
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {

                    string newfileName = file.Replace("\\'", "'");
                    zip.CompressionLevel = 0;
                    zip.AddFile(newfileName, "");
                }

                zip.Save(newFile);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the code once. Which dll you are using? zip.save and ZipFile() methods are saying as not exist in sharpziplib.

Comment: That code sure looks like it works with DotNetZip, not SharpZipLIb.

Comment: @Ramesh.kbvr this code is using sharpziplib.dll, zipfile is the object of class ionnic.zip.dll :) further you can view this how to use ionic.zip.dll in c# http://forums.asp.net/t/1408725.aspx

Comment: I don't know what you mean. To repeat what I said: the code in your post (above) looks like it uses DotNetZip, and not SharpZipLib. As Ramesh pointed out, sharpziplib does not have those classes and methods. Even you yourself apparently pointed out, ZipFile is a class from Ionic.Zip.dll (DotNetZip).